# PHP mysql function always return false on update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have below function to return status, the query can update the table but it still get status `ACCT_NOT_FOUND`, I've been try `$sql->num_rows` or `$sql->affected_rows` but does not work.

```
public function user_exit($uid, $mysqli)
{
    if(empty($uid)){
        return false;
    }
    $q  = "UPDATE `users` SET last_logged_out=now() ";
    $q .= "WHERE uid='".$uid."' ";

    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);

    if($sql->num_rows !== 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



$exit = $api->user_exit($uid, $mysqli);

if($exit !== FALSE){

    $data = array('status'=>'SUCCESS_LOGOUT');

}else{

    $data = array('status'=>'ACCT_NOT_FOUND');
}
```

Comment: Why not rather use `if($exit){ } else { }`. Since you are returning `true` or `false`, a simple `if()` condition would be better than to check for `!== FALSE`

Comment: i think !==  to !=

Comment: are you sure that your query worked perfectly.

Comment: Check $sql->num_rows, what is it returning?

Comment: I've been try both `!=` and `if($exit){ } else { }`, but not working.

Comment: Look at what [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) should return for an UPDATE statement!!! Clue, it isn't a result object

Comment: why not use `$exit === true` in stead of `$exit !== false` the function at this moment can only return true or false, and a double negative is potential cause for confusion

Comment: If your code is accurate then `empty($uid)` is `true`, so the function returns `false`. But clearly it is not accurate, given the stray `public`, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use $mysqli->affected_rows since you are updating not num_rows

```
 if($mysqli->affected_rows !== 0){
        return true;
    }
```

change the function like below

```
public function user_exit($uid, $mysqli)
{
    if(empty($uid)){
        return false;
    }
    $q  = "UPDATE `users` SET last_logged_out=now() ";
    $q .= "WHERE uid='".$uid."' ";

    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);

    if($mysqli->affected_rows !== 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I try either way `affected_rows` and `num_rows`, same happen. I try change query statement to `$q = "SELECT * FROM users"`instead, it work as expected, so the problem should happen in the update query, BUT the update query use directly in phpmyadmin, it did works, i have no idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **num_rows** method with select query.

if you want to get affected row you should try **affected_rows**

Read specific document about affected rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 0){
        return true;
    }
```